Порядок выполнения button.clicked.connect()
Пишу на питоне голосового помощника. 
Есть код второй части - когда я запускаю код и нажимаю кнопку,
код должен сначала поменять картинку в self.label = QLabel(), 
а потом начать записывать голос и переводить его в текст.
Но, почему-то, картинка меняется только после записи голоса и перевода его в текст?
self.pixmap1 = QPixmap('слушает_нач_вариант.jpg')
self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap1)

выполняется последним. 
Можете подсказать, почему, и как это исправить?

main.py:
import time

import speech_recognition as sr
from threading import Thread
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys
from ain2 import the_button_was_clicked1

recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
microphone = sr.Microphone()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
        self.setFixedSize(645, 500)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('говорит.jpg')
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.button = QPushButton("Press Me!")
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        # self.button.clicked.connect(self.govor)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.the_button_was_clicked2)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.the_button_was_clicked1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

    def the_button_was_clicked2(self):
        self.pixmap1 = QPixmap('слушает_нач_вариант.jpg')
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap1)
        print('dssgg')
        #self.button = QPushButton("Press")

    def the_button_was_clicked1(self):
        print('click')
        recognized_data = ""
        with microphone:

            # регулирование уровня окружающего шума
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(microphone, duration=2)

            try:
                print("Listening...")
                audio = recognizer.listen(microphone)

            except sr.WaitTimeoutError:
                print("Can you check if your microphone is on, please?")
                return

            # использование online-распознавания через Google
            try:
                print("Started recognition...")
                recognized_data = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="ru").lower()

            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                pass

            # в случае проблем с доступом в Интернет происходит выброс ошибки
            except sr.RequestError:
                print("Check your Internet Connection, please")

        print(recognized_data)
def application_setup():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    app.exec()
    return

if True:
    application_setup()


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

а зачем вы вообще сделали два разных сигнала на одну кнопку? перенесите изменение картинки в начало своей функции the_button_was_clicked2 и вызывайте только её.

я пытался, но так тоже картинка выводилась в конце, я подумал что картинка меняется только когда функция полностью выполняется и возвращается к init, поэтому и сделал два вызова но это тоже не сработало

В графическом интерфейсе, действия требующие длительного решения, выполняются в дополнительном потоке. 
Выглядит это примерно так:
import sys
#? import time
import speech_recognition as sr
#? from threading import Thread
'''
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsPixmapItem, \
    QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#? from ain2 import the_button_was_clicked1


class SpeechRecognitionThread(QThread):
    about_text = pyqtSignal(str)
    language = "en-US"

    def run(self):
        try:
            r = sr.Recognizer()
            self.about_text.emit("Скажите что-нибудь...")

            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                audio = r.listen(source)

            self.about_text.emit("Анализирую речь...")
            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language=self.language)
            self.about_text.emit('Фраза: "{}"'.format(text))

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            self.about_text.emit("Робот не расслышал фразу")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            self.about_text.emit("Ошибка сервиса: {}".format(e))
        except Exception as e:
            self.about_text.emit("Ошибка: {}".format(e))
        finally:
            self.about_text.emit('')


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)        
        
        self.pixmap1 = QPixmap('img/2.jpg')

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('img/1.jpg')
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self._label = QLabel(
            'Нажмите кнопку SPEAK <br>и скажите что-нибудь.')
        self._label.setStyleSheet(
            "QLabel{color: white; font: 14pt}")
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self._label, 
            alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        
        self.cb_lang = QComboBox()
        self.cb_lang.addItems(["en-US", "ru-RU"])
        self.cb_lang.setCurrentIndex(1)

        self.button = QPushButton(" SPEAK")
        self.button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 16))
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
#        self.button.clicked.connect(self.the_button_was_clicked2)
#        self.button.clicked.connect(self.the_button_was_clicked1)
# !!! +++
        self.button.clicked.connect(self._speech_recognition_start)

        self.pte_result = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.pte_result.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        self.pte_result.setReadOnly(True)        

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cb_lang)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pte_result)
# !!! +++        
        self.thread = SpeechRecognitionThread()
        self.thread.about_text.connect(self._about_text)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self._speech_recognition_finish)

    def _about_text(self, text):
        self.pte_result.appendPlainText(text)
        self._label.setText(text)

    def _speech_recognition_start(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(False)
        self.pte_result.clear()
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap1)        
        self.thread.language = self.cb_lang.currentText()
        self.thread.start()
        
    def _speech_recognition_finish(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(True)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self._label.setText(
            'Нажмите кнопку SPEAK <br>и скажите что-нибудь.')
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
#?    window.setFixedSize(645, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())





@user630602 что не так?
